# Bash parameters array manipulation issue

Tags: bash

I have a problem with my first bash script. I fill an array in for loop and when I try to get an item from it I always get the first element.

```
for (( i = 0; i < ${#*}; i++ )); do
hash=$(md5 -q ${@:$i:1})
modifiedNames[$i]=${@:$i:1}$hash 
done

echo ${modifiedNames[1]}
```

for instance if I call my script like this: ./script.sh file1 file2 i get file1[file1hash]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$@` isn't a real array - it's a shell "Special Parameter", and you need to be a bit more careful with it than other arrays.

The reason for the behaviour you're seeing is that the exact behaviour of the  `${parameter:length:offset}` syntax is special-cased when `parameter` is `@`, and the behaviour is not consistent with the behaviour you'd get if `@` was a real array.

Here's the relevant documentation (**bold** emphasis mine):

> `${`*parameter*`:`*offset*`:`*length*`}`
>
> ... If *parameter* is @, the result is *length* **positional parameters** beginning at *offset*. If *parameter* is @, the result is *length* positional parameters beginning at *offset*. ...

The **positional parameters** are `$0`, `$1`, `$2`, ..., so with this syntax it's behaving as if `$@` contained the script name (`$0`) as well as the parameters to the script (`$1`, `$2`, ...). This is inconsistent with `"$@"` expanding to `"$1" "$2" ...`, but that's life.

You should be able to simplify things (and fix the script) by making a new array instead of using `$@` directly, i.e.

```
new_array=("$@")
for (( i = 0; i < ${#new_array}; i++ )); do
    hash=$(md5 -q ${new_array[@]:$i:1})
    modifiedNames[$i]=${new_array[@]:$i:1}$hash 
done

echo ${modifiedNames[1]}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your loop is behaving funny because it should start with i = 1 and go to i = ${#*}.  Expansion of ${@:0:1} is giving file1 and so is ${@:1:1}.

Try `for (( i = 1; i <= ${#*}; i++ ))`

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating through the arguments array starting at 0, which is the command name. So, if you call your script like `./script.sh file1 file2`, then:

```
${@} = array(
   [0] = ./script,
   [1] = file1,
   [2] = file2
)
```

So you are getting:

```
modifiedNamed = array(
   [0] = md5(./script),
   [1] = md5(file1)
)
```

You should change your `for` loop indexes to:

```
for (( i = 1; i <= ${#*}; i++ )); do
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you *are* getting the second element, but your loop puts the same value in [0] and in [1].

I'm not certain what you are trying to do but it would probably be easier to iterate over the arguments and then keep a separate counter for the array.

```
n=0
for i in "$@"; do
  . . .
  n=$(($n + 1))
done
```

Comment: Ok, but why loop behaves so? I can't see the reason why it puts the same value to array items.